# Building a 3D model Database - Preferably MySql/Postgres/MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unity-game-engine, database-design, 3d-model

I am currently working on creating a library of 3D models created till date by our in-house 3D modellers using Unity3D/Maya/3ds Max, for further analysis and keeping track of each.

So, my question is how to go about storing them?

1. So should I store them in a database or use some kind of storage like AWS S3. They are to be stored in .fbx format. Once stored I would want to perform operations on them, like viewing them online, download etc.
2. Is there any other way/some kind of best practice to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia .fbx format is represented as "binary or ASCII data". This means that you can hardly analyze it using SQL.

You will probably use a simple BLOB (or other binary type) column to store the model itself. This will allow you to control access to models, share them, add comments, store revisions, etc. For viewing or downloading you will pull the whole file content from the database and serve it as binary data.

Comment: Thought so... Just needed someone else to confirm the same